# SQL Server CE on Azure website

Tags: azure, sql-server-ce

Trying to run SQL Server CE on an Azure website, but I am getting error:

> Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8876. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details

Comment: I am not sure you can rely on the file system for this on Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

- Reference System.Data.SqlServerCe 4.0, set "Copy Local" = true.
- Azure runs as a an x86 process (not Amd):
  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE");
- On dev machine find SQLServerCE dependencies: 
  C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Private\x86
- Create SqlServerCE\x86 folder in web project.
- Copy x86 files into new x86 folder:
  sqlceca40.dll
  sqlcecompact40.dll
  sqlceer40EN.dll
  sqlceme40.dll
  sqlceqp40.dll
  sqlcese40.dll
- Add this block to **top** of application_start in global.asax

  ```
      string dest = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath;
      string src = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase + "SqlServerCE\\x86";

      foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(src))
      {
          var fileinfo = new FileInfo(file);
          string destpath = Path.Combine(dest, fileinfo.Name);

          if (!File.Exists(destpath))
          {
              fileinfo.CopyTo(destpath);
          }
      }
  ```

Note: I am not happy with this solution but I can't figure out how to get the files into the bin folder on deployment. post build events don't seem to work. If anyone has a better solution please suggest it.

Comment: you shall not do this on Azure Web Sites if you want a healthy service and you don't want to fight with unknown and unforeseen errors and issues ...

Comment: @astaykov would be nice to hear an alternative, as in "you can use Web Roles/Cloud Services" to add additional installation steps, rather than simple "no you cannot do that on Azure", wouldn't you agree?

Comment: no I wouldn't agree! Even if you install SQL Server CE components on Web Roles, you shall not do that too! The storage on Web/Worker roles is unreliable, as your instance may go in and out at any time. The only viable solution is to have a VM (IaaS), which is not ideal cloud solution and for your case I wouldn't go for a VM. I already listed what are the alternatives in my original answer!

Comment: I think astaykov is missing the  point for doing this. Was working on a VERY small web site where SQL Server prohibited. I planned on deploying this to a Server. I was using Azure as a demonstration location.

Comment: Why ? 1) customer makes using SQL Server nearly impossible. 2) I needed a SQL database. 3) I needed a demo server customer could use. I could have used TinySQL or other file based systems. I know they won't work for more than two users, but I only had one. If the customer ever decided they needed two users, then they would have to figure out what database to  run on. (You can't fix stupid) For my purposes of a demonstration site, this worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use SQL Server CE on [Azure Web Sites](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/websites/). Using Azure Web Sites you have to use external database - such as [Azure SQL Database](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/) or [MySQL](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-php-create-mysql-database/).

Generally speaking for the cloud and any cloud service (IaaS, PaaS, SaaS), you shall never rely on local file system, but rather persist your files on a durable storage such as Azure Blob Storage. Thus you can't (shall not) use services like SQL Server CE.

Comment: I agree with the "best practice" you propose, but my customer is lacking in the ability to make good IT decisions. My ultimate deployment will likely be SQLServerCE - a terrible choice for any multi-threaded application, but I will only have a few users. By using SqlCE, I can easily migrate to SQLServer if we have the need for more users while being able to demonstrate progress on an Azure server, instead of the customer's crippled and aggravating  environment. They have an institutional bias against SQLServer, and ORacle has never released a provider for EF6.